# Generalized way to remove empty row given by aggregate functions in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, exists

The below query would give an empty **NULL** row when no data is present in the Table or when **WHERE** fails.

```
SELECT MAX(Number) AS Number
  FROM Table
 WHERE Number > 10;
```

The NULL row result looks like this:-

|  | Number |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | NULL |

So to detect if the query gives actual data or not I had to do this:-

```
SELECT 1
  FROM (
           SELECT MAX(Number) AS Number
             FROM Table
            WHERE Number > 10
       )
 WHERE Number IS NOT NULL;
```

Now, this will give me **1** if a max number exists and **0** if (max it doesn't exist or empty table or WHERE Number < 10).

So, is this how we generally tackle the empty row produced by the aggregate function, or is there a more generalized way to do that.

An example SQLite [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/0b4534/2/0) showcasing the use case.

Comment: Please don't change the question after it has been answered; that is not allowed. Also, please don't provide responses or answer follow-ups in the question body. If you have information relevant to the answer, post it as a comment under the answer instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overcomplicating things with the use of the aggregate function `MAX()`.

This part of your code:

```
EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM (
          SELECT MAX(TourCompletionDateTime) AS TourCompletionDateTime
          FROM Details
          WHERE TourCompletionDateTime < '2022-07-26T09:36:00.730589Z'
        )
        WHERE TourCompletionDateTime IS NOT NULL
      )
```

is equivalent to just:

```
EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM Details
        WHERE TourCompletionDateTime < '2022-07-26T09:36:00.730589Z'
      )
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.39&fiddle=d7f229db1a2859c0450d5f12c0446c58).